# Open a file in a shared folder in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I am trying to open a pdf file residing in a windows shared folder from my cocoa application.

I am trying to use the NSWorkSpace openFile method to open the file and I am passing a path similar to @"smb:\192.168.2.1\sharedFolderName\my.pdf.

However I am unable to open the file. Do I have to mount the shared folder before opening the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper URL for shared folder is

```
smb://[[domain;]username[:password]@]server[/share[/path]]
```

So in your example it should be

```
@"smb://192.168.2.1/sharedFolderName/my.pdf"
```

Comment: Note that this opens Finder and reveals the file, it does not open the PDF in Preview.

Comment: You may need to use openFile(.., withApplication: "Preview")